# Assigning the values to another stack in c++

Tags: c++, stack

Is this line valid in a program, which is using stack?

s1.top()==s2.push(j);

This shows that the value of the top element of a stack(s1) is assigned to another stack s2.

Where j='A';

If not, then what are the alternates to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not valid, and definitely not how you describe.  Looking at the [documentation for stack in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/), method push has return type void (i.e. does not return anything).

Note that == is a comparison of two values, whereas = is an assignment (assign right hand side to left hand side).

To remove from top of stack s1 and push onto s2, you should do :

```
s2.push(s1.top());
s1.pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid, because [std::stack::push](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/push/) returns void

If you want to know if `s1.top()` is contained in `s2`, you should use `std::find`